# Python Tkinter - Toplevel MoveInAnimation

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, move, toplevel

Is there an option to simply move a `Tkinter TopLevel()` window on runtime by using an animation? I thought about a smooth moveInAnimation triggered by a button. 
Here is some code snippet:

```
from Tkinter import Toplevel

class MoveInTopLevel(Toplevel):
    '''
    Animated MoveInToplevel.
    '''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.overrideredirect(1)

    def move_in_from_bottom(self, rootHeight):
        y = rootHeight
        y = max(y-1, 0)
        s = "100x100+0+" + str(y)
        print s

        self.geometry(s)
        self.deiconify()

        if  y > 0:
            self.after(5, self.move_in_from_bottom(y))
```

Called for example in the mainFunction like this:

```
window = MoveInTopLevel()
window.move_in_from_bottom(480) # That's some resolution (height)
```

When I run this, I get the window correctly displayed at final position (0,0) and all coordinates are printed out from (0,479) down to (0,0). But there are no windows displayed in between, altough I am calling `deiconify()`.
Can anybody help me out? I am confused. ^^

Thank's in advance.
Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line of code:

```
self.after(5, self.move_in_from_bottom(y))
```

In that line of code you are immediately calling `self.move_in_from_bottom` *before* the call to after, and the result of that call (`None`) is being passed to the `after` command.

The `after` method needs a *reference* to a function. A common way to do that is to use lambda, though functools.partial works well, too.

Here is an example using lambda:

```
self.after(5, lambda y=y: self.move_in_from_bottom(y))
```